# Error on ruby functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-test

This is  my test

```
def test_create
  get :new    
  assert_template "admin/supplier/new"
  assert_difference 'Supplier.count' do
    post :create, :supplier => {:name => 'Juan', :province => 'provincia'}
    assert_response :redirect
    assert_redirected_to :action => 'index'      
  end
  assert_equal 'Supplier Juan was succesfully created.', flash[:notice]
end
```

when i execute it this is the error that it shows

```
test_create(Admin::SupplierControllerTest) [supplier_controller_test.rb:25]:
expecting <"admin/supplier/new"> but rendering with <"">
```

What is failing on assert_template "admin/supplier/new"??

Comment: okay. what is your question now?

Comment: When you split this into two tests (i.e. test `new` and `create` individually), does `new` still fail?

Comment: Do you have some sort of user authentication in place? Could it be the "new" is redirecting to some other page because of a missing current user (or a current user who's not admin) ?

Comment: yes i have user authentication